# API skips authenticity verification with versionist gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, csrf

I am trying to implement verify authenticity for my Rails app, which seems to be a Rails feature

And can't figure out where the callback is failing...

So here is my applicaiton controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

Here is my API controller:

```
class V1::ManagerLeadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    manager_lead = ManagerLead.create!(manager_lead_params)
    render json: manager_lead
  end

  private
  def manager_lead_params
    params.require(:manager_lead).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :company,
       :format, :requested_date, :meeting_type, :has_complited_wholesale_investor_form
    )
  end
end
```

And here are my logs:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/manager_leads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-24 10:29:46 +1100
Processing by V1::ManagerLeadsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"manager_lead"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "email"=>"", "phone"=>"", "company"=>"", "meeting_type"=>""}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "manager_leads" ("company", "created_at", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "meeting_type", "phone", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["company", ""], ["created_at", "2014-10-23 23:29:46.833290"], ["email", ""], ["first_name", ""], ["last_name", ""], ["meeting_type", ""], ["phone", ""], ["updated_at", "2014-10-23 23:29:46.833290"]]
   (7.6ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 9.4ms)
```

Can't verity CSRF token authenticity, however the request is completed with 200OK response :(

If I do something like this:

```
if verified_request?
  manager_lead = ManagerLead.create!(manager_lead_params)
  render json: manager_lead
else
  render json: { error: 'Unprocessed entity' }, status: 422
end
```

Then the app starts to work alright:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/manager_leads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-24 10:30:59 +1100
Processing by V1::ManagerLeadsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"manager_lead"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "email"=>"", "phone"=>"", "company"=>"", "meeting_type"=>""}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 3ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm using

```
Rails 4.1.5
versionist gem
jquery-ui-rails # for form submission
```

Answer (score 0):

ok the answer was:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```